# PostgreSQL Schema doesn't exists : Error 3F000

Tags: amazon-redshift

When I am trying to fetch some records from a RedShift DB(PostgreSQL) via Program or IDE (Aginity), I am getting the below exception

Sample QUERY:

```
SELECT * FROM db_name.schema_name.table_name;
```

Result:

ERROR: 3F000: schema 'schema_name' does not exist

It returns correct results only if I am executing an IDE option to fetch Top 100 records. (i.e. with IDE created query and executed by IDE automatically). And If I am executing the same query again, I am getting the same exception.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Omit the `db_name.` from your query.

Comment: Thanks. I have used with db_name and without db_name. Same result.

Comment: Can you post the actual query? My guess is that there is a dot somewhere in schema name.